# User Mapping SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql, ssms

I am using the sp_addrolemember procedure to give a user access.  The command works but can anyone explain why the "Map" checkbox isn't checked under the "User Mapping" in the their properties? Or is there a way to have the box checked?

I am using a HTML interface with Python to give users access but if I go into SQL Management Studio it is confusing because it looks like they don't have permission when just scrolling through mappings for that user.

```
USE [105494-0000] EXEC sp_addrolemember 'permission', 'user_name'
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the user first

```
CREATE USER [testUser] FOR LOGIN [testLogin]
```

Then

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'testUser'
```

Comment: If the user exists, then you don't need to create it. the last statement will be enough

Comment: This still doesn't explain why the "map" checkbox doesn't get checked in the users properties.  I am looking for a way to have it checked even though the command works as expected because it's misleading when you view there permissions from within Management Studio

Comment: If it's not checked then it means it is not mapped. BTW: i tested it and the box is checked.

Comment: Is the box checked for map under "users mapped to this location" on the first image or is it checked for db_datareader under "Database role membership for..."